# Peer to Peer using Ethernet Module

Tags: ethernet, networking

I'm beginner here at arduino stuff. i just started learning arduino and i have this small homework where i NEEDED to connect 2 arduino using ethernet shield or module ONLY over a distance of 20 meters.

I don't have my modules yet but i want to atleast study it now while i'm waiting for it. I can't seem to see any tutorials about it nor anyone tried it. How can i do this? i hope you can help me and give some insights, links, etc reference. Thanks :)

EDIT:
I had in mind where these arduino will have their own identity, 1st arduino will be receiving only some data coming from 2nd arduino. The 2nd arduino will have sensors and read them then sends them to 1st arduino. Now, i like my 2nd arduino to have a power source coming from the 1st arduino to save power supply installation and since it'll be like a remote arduino. Thus has anyone has experience applying PoE on arduino?

Comment: PoE uses 48V ... if you want to use actual PoE injectors, then you will need to use a power supply at each arduino

Answer (score 2):

You will need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) to connect two Ethernet shields peer to peer.

Then you configure the Ethernet library to use static IP address. Use 192.168.1.1 and .2 address. (Or other 192.168.x.x address). Set subnet 255.255.255.0. Gateway should be the IP address of the other Arduino.

Comment: hi juraj, :D thanks a lot, never knew i need to consider that, i thought i just have to buy ethernet cable, i'll drop by my progress here and notify if it work

Comment: i was thinking also regarding PoE application, goal was 1st arduino is like the server and only reads send messages from 2nd arduino as client since it will have sensors connected to it and i want 2nd arduino to have its power source coming from where 1st arduino is put. would that be possible?

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with PoE and having Arduino as a PoE source is not so common, I think